# Laravel Queue Worker

Tags: laravel, server, queue, centos7

I have added this woker in etc/superviord.config for one project, I would like to make it work for multiple projects I mean for xyz, project also so should I need to copy and paste below all code or just have to add only one more command line?
[image]

Comment: You need one section like this per queue you want to listen to, and for each different queue worker you want to run. Personally I have one file per project and have all the workers I need for one single project in that one file but you can use the same file for every project or a different file for every project and queue. It's up to you really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to copy-paste your program definition to separate supervisor processes.

And about the folder. You should use the `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/`.
Just create the config file with `SOMETHING-LIKE-A-PROJECT-NAME.conf` and put your `program` definition into it.

And then check that your `/etc/supervisord.conf` contains the include section:

```
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, what I have done is I have copied the above-written program to new one with different program definition and I run these commands and lastly for new program name to make it work
 `sudo supervisorctl reread`

`sudo supervisorctl update`

`sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*`

Comment: Pls update the answer with this so I can accept I mean for the future, if anyone comes around we should have this solution too along side!

Comment: @MuhammadTariq you can just run `sudo service supervisor restart` (when using `ubuntu`).